# UITableView & UICollectionView performance optimisation

Tags: ios, objective-c, performance, uitableview, uicollectionview

Hello colleagues Apple developers!

I am creating an iOS application for both iPhone & iPad. The **performance** of `UITableView` and `UICollectionView` is very important feature in my application.

After long time spent for optimising, human eye can't tell the difference while scroll happens. Although, profiler still finds some issues.

1. The first inefficient thing is dequeuing. I have a `UITableViewCell` object, which user interface is created by using **.xib** files and **auto layout constraints**. Although, the time profiler instrument complains about the performance while dequeuing this specific cell.

[image]

2. One more problem I can't understand is a `NSString` setting as `UILabel`'s text. This setter method is executed in method `- tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.

[image]

3. One more problem, that might be related with previous one, is a `UIImage` setting as `UIImageView`'s image. This method is also executed in method `- tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` and doesn't trigger any download or etc.

[image]

`UITableViewCell` objects, described above, are default size & really simple. The content view of the cell contains only 2 subviews: `UILabel` and `UIImageView`.

Images are downloaded according to [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html)'s example.

```
// Asks the data source for a cell to insert in a particular location of the table view.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Dequeues & initializes category table view cell.
    CategoryTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CategoryTableViewCellIdentifier];

    APICategory *category = [self.categories objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    if (category.thumbnail)
    {
        [cell updateThumbnailWithCategory:category];
    }

    else
    {
        if (!tableView.dragging && !tableView.decelerating)
        {
            [category thumbnailWithSuccess:^(UIImage *thumbnail)
            {
                if ([tableView.visibleCells containsObject:cell])
                {
                    [cell updateThumbnailWithCategory:category];
                }
            }

            failure:^(NSError *error)
            {
                // Handle thumbnail receive failure here!
            }];
        }

        [cell updateThumbnailWithPlaceholder];
    }

    cell.category = [self.categories objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

Specific images used in this case are `.png` images **300x300** resolution and 24 kb of size.

These are the problems related with the **performance** of `UITableView` and `UICollectionView`.

Can anyone explain me, what could be the reasons for any of those issues?

Also, is there a way to improve it?

Comment: Recommendation 1: show your code! Recommendation 2: explain what your actual problem is!

Comment: What kind of code are you talking about? I have already provided some code samples.

Comment: how "big" are your _cells_ if you need to draw __174 times__ in a cycle? and what are in those _cells_? how many subviews, sublayers do they have? what kinda custom visual effects/layers are you using in those cells? are you loading images? how big are they? which kinda __performance__ you'd like to optimise for? faster code in runtime? less battery consumption? using less memory? your question is too broad like this...

Comment: I cannot see any code from you - all I see are images. Images of two lines of code without ANY context.

Comment: @TomKortney, according to your update, it seems you are using images; how big are those images? are you using thumbnail for your cells only, or loading the whole image in one? where the images are coming from? are they local? or fetched from an external source?

Comment: @holex, I have updated my question with additional details. The cells are stupid simple, just `UILabel` and `UIImageView` in cell's content view. No visual effects. Yes, I am loading images lazily according to Apple example. **Most important** at the moment when provided lines are executed, images are already completely downloaded.

Comment: @TomKortney, show us, please, how you load the images; and tell us more about the images actual size.

Comment: @luk2302 If you would just specify, what specific code you would require to have a better understanding of the problem, I would be glad to show it for you. Although, you wouldn't see anything special, it is just registered cells are dequeued, model object is received from data source & set to cell. Also, image download according to Apple's example...

Comment: @TomKortney, could you please share more information about 1.) _how you load the image_, 2.) _how big the images are you load_; that would be extremely helpful to identify your performance issue.

Comment: @holex, is it better now? Is there anything else I could provide?

Comment: the `APICategory` does not seem like being part of the Apple's foundation; what is that (probably) 3rd party stuff? you still have not shared any information about the size of the images; and how many you are showing at the same time on the screen; so, please...

Comment: This is a subclass of `JSONModel`, with the additional method to download the image using `AFNetworking`.

Comment: so you are fetching the images on the fly, those might not be downloaded at all when you present the cell; but you initiate the download procedure when you need to present he cell... and for that you are using a 3rd party library (which may or may not optimised for smooth execution)... altogether the Instruments point to dequeue's performance – have you set the _reuse-identifier_ properly for your cell?

Comment: I am pretty sure, that the problems are not related with download operations. All download and other heavy operations are handled in background. The heaviest operations are provided in question above. Identifier is set correctly.